# Filter nested $elemMatch in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this dataModel

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5f0a9c07b001406068c073c1"), 

"EmailData" : [
    {

        "Attachments" : {

            "Files" : [
                {
                    "Name" : "a.txt" 

                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : "b.txt"
                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : "c.txt"

                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

I want to filter those documents that their name elements insides the Files array be exactly the same as a specific array.
Consider I have this array :`{"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"}`. I want to write a query to compare what is inside the Files element with this array. In my example condition is met but if the array is like:

```
{"a.txt", "b.txt"}
```

It does not meet. I know I have to use multiple $elemMatch but it does not work. Is there any ways to write it without aggregate?

Comment: EmailDate is an array, do you need to check any of the array element satisfy the condition?

Comment: @varman, yes, if any of the array elements meet the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing an exact comparison, try for example:

```
{'EmailData.Attachments.Files': [{Name: 'a.txt'},{Name: 'b.txt'},{Name:'c.txt'}]}
```

Or to allow matching in any order:

```
{'EmailData.Attachments.Files': {$all: [{Name: 'a.txt'},{Name: 'b.txt'},{Name:'c.txt'}], $size: 3}}
```